# Angular combine list using concat returns empty

Tags: javascript, angular, list, typescript, concatenation

I am trying to implement a function which would eventually return a concatenated list.

When the user selects the node, an EventEmitter emits it. It is in the TreeNode format:

```
  displayName:   string;
  children:      TreeNode<T>[];
  selected:      boolean;
  collapsed?:    boolean;
  indeterminate: boolean;
  selectable:    boolean;
  value:         T;
```

I am then passing this node as an input to my function. However, according to my current implementation, I get multiple lists (one for every node that is selected).

I wanted just one concatenated list. When I select a node, "returnTrees" will have the correct list. On selection of another node, `console.log(returnTrees)` will display the previous list(for first selected node) as well as the new list.

slice.component.ts:

```
 public onSliceChange(event:TreeNode<string>):void {
      if(event.selected || event.indeterminate) {
      this.selections.push(event);

      this.selections.forEach(tree => {
        let selectedNodes:TreeNode<string>[] = tree.children.filter(child => child.selected || child.indeterminate);
        let returnTrees:TreeNode<string>[] = [];

        selectedNodes.forEach(node => {
          var tempTree:TreeNode<string> = new TreeNode<string>();
          tempTree.displayName = node.displayName;
          tempTree.value = tree.value;
          tempTree.children = [];
          node.children.forEach(child => tempTree.children = tempTree.children.concat(TreeNode.getAllCheckedNodes(child)));
          returnTrees.push(tempTree);
        });
         console.log(returnTrees);   //prints all lists for all selected nodes
      });

    }
  }
```

I tried adding :

```
tempList: TreeNode<string>[] =[];
this.tempList.concat(returnTrees);
```

But "this.tempList" always is empty in this case (even on node selection).

How can I combine the lists and get a single list? Is this possible? 
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm unclear on your question.  It looks like you have a concept of multiple selections, and each selection can have multiple selected nodes.  Is that correct?  Can you clarify what is the content you want in the single list?  Do you want the concatenation of the `children` lists of all of the selected nodes of all of the selections?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple selections, and each selection can have multiple children (which can be selected too). I want the concatenated list which will have the selections (based on the order in which they are selected) and they'll have the "children" inside of them - in the "children" tag of TreeNode. returnTrees has the correct list, but instead of having a list for every top-level selection, I wanted a concatenated list of all the selected nodes.